# Movie recording certificate?

Tags: credits

I am watching The Lady from Shanghai (1947) and in opening the credits at the bottom of one of the pages it reads:

> [mp A/A]   Western Electric RECORDING   [I.A.T.S.E.]
>           APPROVED...CERTIFICATE NO.12111

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

First off, IATSE stands for *International Alliance of Theatrical Stage Employees*, a union representing theatrical stage employees, moving picture technicians, artists and allied crafts of the United States, its Territories and Canada,

The task of sound recording and production mixing didn't always use independent studio equipment. The manufacturers of the sound equipment kept title to the equipment and only leased it to the studios so the studios could perform their work.

> If you were a production mixer in the early 1930’s, you didn’t have a lot of choices when it came to sound mixing equipment. For starters, there were only two manufacturers, Western Electric and RCA. **Studios did not own the equipment. Instead, it was leased from the manufacturers, and the studio paid a licensing fee for the use of the equipment (readily evidenced by the inclusion of either “Western Electric Sound Recording” or “Recorded by RCA Photophone Sound System” in the end credits)**. Both the equipment, as well as the related operating manuals, were tightly controlled by the manufacturers. For example, **Western Electric manuals had serial numbers assigned to them, corresponding to the equipment on lease by the studio**. These were large multi-volume manuals, consisting of hundreds of pages of detailed operating instructions, schematics, and related drawings. If you didn’t work at a major studio, there is no way you would even be able to obtain the manuals (much less comprehend their contents).
>   <sub>*source:* [IATSE Local 695 Quarterly Magazine (Volume 10, Issue 3, Summer 2018)](https://magazine.local695.com/magazine/summer-2018/the-way-we-were-mixers-past-present-part-1)</sub>

[image]

What your seeing is a certificate identification (roughly equivalent to an invoice or purchase order) that proves the **use** of the Western Electric recording equipment was bought and paid for.

This is somewhat different from the use and promotion of modern sound technology like [Dolby Content Services](https://www.dolby.com/us/en/professional/cinema/industry/content-services.html).